# No package manager in WEKA GUI

Tags: machine-learning, package, weka, libsvm

I installed different versions of WEKA. In all these versions the package manger is not showing up under the Tool tab in the Weka GUI Chooser Window. My machine is MAC. I did find the Package manger in WEKA when I installed it on my Windows machine.
My question is how to add the Package manger to WEKA on MAC.

How to add InputMappedClassifier package and use it in Weka GUI. if there is no solution for the above issue.

Comment: It should be there, are you using a version >=3.7.2?

Comment: I downloaded 3.7.10 , 3.7.11, and 3.7.13. All these versions don't include the the package manger. My friend has the  3.7.10 version installed on his MAC. it includes the package manger.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot (or text) of what you see under your Tools menu? Also, does your `weka.log` have any error information? _(The `weka.log` might be in your `Console` application in your machine's `/Applications/Utilities/` folder.)_

Comment: What I see under Tools menu are: arffViewer, sqlViewer, and Bayes net editor.

Answer (score -1):

Try downloading the development version from 3.8, this should work.